# Variable handling Functions in java

Tags: java, php, object, primitive-types

I'm new to the java language. I'm a php developer. There exist a lot of [Variable handling Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.var.php) in the php language.

But I find it hard to imagine there aren't any built in functions that check whether value is numeric, is null, etc...

Can anyone explain why this is? Why does java not provide simple functions such as these?

Comment: "But i imagine any in build function is not check a value is numeric, is null, etc..." Can you rephrase that?! Java is statically typed, therefore most (if not all) of those variable handling functions do not make sense in Java.

Comment: Because they would be completely pointless, since you know the types of your variables anyway.

Comment: That's what I said in my answer below, but apparently someone isn't satisfied.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi - You were downvoted because your code examples were incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> But i imagine any in build function is not check a value is numeric, is null, etc...
>
> Why java is not provide simple functions such like this?

**First reason**: Java supports method overloading.

In Java, you typically don't write a single method that handle all sorts of arguments with all sorts of different types.  Instead, you can write multiple overloads of the same method: same method name with different declared argument types, and/or different numbers of declared arguments.

The compiler sorts out *at compile time* which overloaded method to call based on the static types of the argument expressions.

In this model, there is no need to a bunch of functions for sorting out whether values are numeric, null, etcetera.

**Second reason**: Java does not allow primitive types and object types to be used interchangeably.

For example you cannot declare an argument type that would accept both an `int` value and a `String` value.  And an `int` argument type can never accept a `null`.

(Actually, the primitive wrapper classes like `Integer` and Java 5's addition of autoboxing / unboxing tend to blur the distinction.  But the underlying hard distinction between primitive and reference types remains.  Autoboxing is syntactic sugar.)

**Third reason**: There is `instanceof` and testing for `== null`.

As @Malik points out, in the cases where the tests do make sense in Java, they can be implemented with built-in constructs, without resorting to library "functions".  The functions are unnecessary.

(AFAIK, no mainstream 3rd-party utility library has implemented the equivalent of the PHP functions you are talking about ... which supports the view that they are unnecessary.  If enough people thought the functions were necessary, there would be a library and we would know about it.)

---

It is also worth noting that most of the "variable handling functions" are to do with dynamically declared variables in PHP.  Java doesn't support that.  If you want to implement a dynamic binding between names (strings) and values in Java, use a `Map` class.

Comment: The method overloading is a great concept that I missed out on. Definitely important

Answer (score 1):

PHP lets you store almost any value in any variable, and converts between types as necessary. Java does not automatically convert between most types - if you want a conversion, you have to do it yourself.

All of the `is_something` functions would be pointless - you know the type of a variable since you declared it!

If you have a reference to an object, you can determine the type of the object (*not* the variable) that it refers to using `instanceof` or reflection:

```
Object x = "hello";
// the variable x is of type Object, but it refers to a String. How can we tell?

System.out.println(x instanceof Integer); // prints "false"
System.out.println(x instanceof String); // prints "true"
System.out.println(x.getClass().getName()); // prints "java.lang.String"
```

However, most of the time, this simply isn't something you need to do.

So, all of the `is_something` functions are unnecessary, and all of the `somethingval` functions wouldn't fit well in the language (although there's no technical reason they couldn't exist). What else is there?

- `get_defined_vars` - again, redundant. You know what variables are defined because you defined them!
- `empty` (returns true if a variable doesn't exist or contains false). Using a variable that doesn't exist is a compile-time error, so you can just use `thing == false` (or `!thing` if it's a boolean) instead of `empty(thing)`.
- `get_resource_type` - the closest match in Java is `thing.getClass().getName()` instead of `get_resource_type(thing)`.
- `gettype` - useless for the same reason the `is_something` functions are useless.
- `import_request_variables` - The language Java has no built-in concept of GET variables, POST variables or cookies. Even if it did, this wouldn't work very well, because you'd have to declare all the variables anyway.
- `is_null` - use `thing == null` instead of `is_null(thing)`.
- `isset` - again, you can't use variables that don't exist. So just use `thing != null` instead of `isset(thing)`.
- `serialize` and `unserialize` - Java has a serialization system, which is more complex but more flexible. Look up `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`.
- `settype` - makes no sense, as the type of a variable cannot be changed.
- `strval` - use `String.valueOf`.
- `unset` - makes no sense. Variables exist until the end of their scope.
- `print_r` and `var_dump` and `var_export` - the only ones that might actually be useful and don't already exist. Sadly, it just doesn't exist, though you can get something similar if you override toString in all of your classes.

Comment: If someone wanted to, they could implement `print_r`, `var_dump` and `var_export` using reflection (though not for local vars ...)  But I think most Java programmers you steer clear of them most of the time.  (Ick!!)

Answer (score 0):

First of all why check variable type when you explicitly define a variable with a type. Secondly, you can check the type in Java although you should already know the type.

```
Integer x = 3;

if (x instanceof Integer) {
    System.out.println("Integer");
} 

String s = "test";

if (s instanceof String) {
    System.out.println("String");
}
```

Comment: clearly you still didn't test it, because this still doesn't compile.

Comment: Fixed, again. I'm very clumsy, forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

PHP as you are aware doesn't tend to care what you store in a variable, you declare a name, give it a value and it will try and interpret it itself. In Java, you explicitly declare the type of variable you would like.

Something like an integer (whole number) can be presented by the primitive data type `int`, so you could use

```
int myNumber = 7;
```

And the code would know for sure that this is an integer, as you have explicitly stated that this is the case. Refer to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for other java primitives.

If you are using a String (which is an object) in Java, you can use the function isEmpty() to determine if there are any characters in it. You can do a check on objects in Java to see if they have been instantiated by using object == null.

Some compilers will actually give you warnings if you have not initialised variables before you check them, whether these are objects or primitives.

To get a good feel of how data types work in Java, refer to the Oracle documentation I linked, it is very useful, and ill contain a lot of information of other aspects of Java you may have questions with.